# Bundle Prisma Client in a module

Tags: typescript, prisma, rollup, monorepo, lerna

I'm having questions, on prisma generated clients, maybe I'm doing things wrong.

I Have a monorepo with the following modules dependency tree:

```
Module A -
           |- Module C
Module B -
```

- Module A and B both have a prisma client in them, and both export their Prisma client to be used in module C.
- I don't want them to build their respective clients in ./node_modules/ because it's a Lerna monorepo and base ./node_modules/ is shared and I want to be sure I won't have any interferences, so idealy, I want to specify an output for both.

The problem is, when I build and bundle modules A and B (with rollup), they only resolve the index of the generated client, but not all other dependencies (./runtime/ folder, .d.ts files), thus not resolving types in imported Module A and B clients, and more annoyingly crashing at runtime because of the missing ./runtime/ folder.

I can copy every files one by one and rewrites the paths to make it match, but I don't think it should be that hard to bundle a prisma client. So I'm pretty sure I've missed the point or misunderstood something essential.

Do you have any insights on how to handle it ?

Thanks